# Rewriting $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$ and $\frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have some short questions regarding roots. There are probably rules for those, but I couldn't find the general rules for these:

$1.$ If we want to find

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$$

What is the rule called where we can rewrite it to this?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\ln(x)}$$

$2.$ Why is $\frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$?

Why is it wrong to expand this with $()^2$, leading to $\frac{(2\sqrt{x})^2}{x} = \frac{4x}{x^2} = \frac{4}{x}$?

$3.$ How does $\frac{1}{n} \cdot \big( \sqrt{n^2+n} +n \big )$ lead to $\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}} +1$? How can you multiply $\frac{1}{n}$ with $\sqrt{n^2+n}$?

Comment: Hi, please ask only one question in a post.

Comment: Hi, they are all more or less related to each other.

Comment: (1): Remember that $e^{\ln(b)} = b$ and here let $x^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$ play the role of $b$.  Next remember that $\ln(a^b) = b\ln(a)$.  Next, (2) you ask "*why is it wrong to expand with $(~)^2$?*"  Why?  Very simply because $a$ is not the same thing as $a^2$... $3$ is not equal to $9$... so if you squared it, you had better square root it again after.  The easier explanation is to see that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$ can be "*multiplied by one*" where $1$ here is of the form $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ and you get the result.  For (3) remember that $a\cdot\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a^2\cdot b}$

Comment: (*warning, $a\cdot \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a^2\cdot b}$ is true only for non-negative real $a$ and it is dangerous to do if $a$ is negative or complex*)

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you so much for the explanation. I understand it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do we rewrite these:

> $1. \ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac 1 {\sqrt x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\frac 1 {\sqrt{x}} \cdot \ln (x)}$

> $2. \ \displaystyle \dfrac{2\sqrt{x}}{x} = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$

> $3. \ \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \left( \sqrt{n^2+n}+n \right)=\sqrt{1+\frac 1 n}+1.$

Answer.

$1. \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac {!} {\sqrt{x}}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(e^{\ln(x)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac {1}{\sqrt{x}} \cdot \ln(x)}.$

$2. 2\cdot \left(\sqrt{x}^2\right)=2x, 2\sqrt{x}=\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{x}}, \dfrac{2\sqrt{x}}{x}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x}}.$

$3.\dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \left( \sqrt{n^2+n}+n\right)=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n^2}\left( 
n^2+n \right)}+\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot n=\sqrt{1+\frac 1 n}+1.$